# defaultThemeDefinition - no CommunityThemeDefinition observed when attempting to deploy/validate change set

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning-bolt

Using the new Lightning Bolt Solution feature and trying to validate in a change set in Production, getting the following error from the change set when validating:

```
in field: defaultThemeDefinition - 
no CommunityThemeDefinition named My_Community_Template found
```

[Known issue here is shown as "Fixed"](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001BdhQAE), however there appear to be no orgs where this has been resolved. The workaround suggests using an unmanaged package, however when I add the solution to a package it pulls in a bunch of stuff that already exists in Production (fields, page layouts etc), so pretty sure it would fail to install since they're already in the destination org.

Are there any other workarounds available?